# Why is the expected number coin tosses to get $HTH$ is $10$?

Tags: probability, intuition

Can someone please explain why is the expected number of coin tosses to get the sequence of $HTH$ is $10$? What is the intuition and formulas behind this?

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? :)

Comment: @Shaun well I was trying to use markov chains in order to solve this. I know how to to draw the matrix but I don't remember how to calculate the expected number of times it takes to go from one state to another, here being going from state zero which is before we tossed any coins to state HTH(3 if we start from zero). I thought using stationary distributions but I'm not sure. Also I was curious about solving this using Geometric distribution if possible.

Comment: Were you actually able to reach a solution based on the accepted answer?

Comment: It sounded similar to what I have heard and I'm working on it. But it also gave me a lead to what I'm looking for using markov chains. I was interested in both solutions yours and his so I chose one.

Comment: I note that you avoid carefully to answer my query.

Comment: Some intuition: $1/8$ of the consecutive triples in a long string of flips are HTH, however the expected waiting time is more than 8 because some of those occurrances overlap with a previous HTH (by one flip) and those, in effect, don't end a waiting game for HTH (call them "bad"). In fact, you can see that on average 1/4 of the good HTH's will be followed by TH giving a "bad" occurrence. So the expected waiting time is $8(1 + 1/4) = 10$. I'm omitting details but that's the idea and it works -- all about overlapping occurrences of the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Denote the state before tossing  $\emptyset$, you start in it. If your first toss is $H$, you proceed to the next state, otherwise stay in $\emptyset$. From state $1$ there's no way back to state $\emptyset$, but if you toss $H$ you stay in state 1 (since you need $HTH$). You should get something like

$\mathbf{P} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0\\0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

EDIT the equation for mean first hitting time until set $R$ from state $1$ is

$$
m_{1, R} = p_{1,2} m_{2, R} + (1-p_{1,2})m_{1,R}
$$
in your case you need 3 equations with 3 unknowns.

Comment: would you know how to calculate the expected number of time is takes to get HTH using this matrix?

Comment: Please see the edit

Answer (score 6):

Let the expected number of tosses until we get the pattern HTH be $a$.

Let the expected *additional* waiting time given that we have just tossed an H (and are not finished) be $b$.

Let the expected additional waiting time given that our last two tosses have been HT be $c$.

By conditioning, we have the following equations:

$$a=1+\frac{1}{2}b+\frac{1}{2}a;$$
This is because on our first toss, we have used up a toss. If we got an H, our expected additional time is $b$. If we got a T, we have made no progress, and our additional expected time is $a$.

$$b=1+\frac{1}{2}b+\frac{1}{2}c.$$

$$c=1+\frac{1}{2}a.$$

Since $a$, $b$, and $c$ are clearly finite, we can find them by solving  the above system of three linear equations.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen a way to answer these types of problem here - https://www.codechef.com/wiki/tutorial-expectation

Using the technique described in the link, the answer can be found out as:

Let $x$ be the expected number of tosses required to get $HTH$, then we can find $x$ recursively:

1. If the first toss is $T$, then expected number of tosses now are $x+1$.
2. If the first toss is $H$, then two cases:

   1. If the second toss is $H$, then expected number of tosses now are $x$ (one is wasted in the first toss, but the second toss is still useful)
   2. If the second toss is $T$, then two cases:

      1. If the third toss is $H$, then the expected number is 3.
      2. If the third toss is $T$, then the expected number is $x+3$.

Adding all above mentioned cases:

$$x = \frac{1}{2}(x+1)+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}(x)+ \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}(3)+\frac{1}{2}(x+3)))$$
Solving the above expression give $x=10$.

Comment: How is it x + 3? the previous 2 cases are useful the third one is not right?

Comment: None of the prior outcomes are useful in that branch. HTT--> need 3 new rolls to get to HTH.

Comment: The key insight here, to me, is HH -->x (point 2. subpoint 1.)

Answer (score 2):

*Intuition*? Dunno... Anyhow, consider $u$, $v$ and $w$ the mean number of draws necessary to produce H starting from nothing, HT starting from H, and HTH starting from HT, respectively. We are after the mean number of draws $t$ necessary to produce HTH, which is $t=u+v+w$.

Note that $u=2$ (first success when a success is H) and $v=2$ (first success when a success is T). If the first draw after HT is H, this draw produces HTH while if the first draw is T, one wasted one draw and one is back at the initial situation hence $t$ supplementary  draws will be necessary. Thus, $w=\frac12\cdot1+\frac12\cdot(1+t)$.

This yields $t=u+v+w=4+w=4+1+\frac12\cdot t$, that is, $t=10$.

*Exercise:* Adapt the proof to uneven probabilities $p$ for H and $q=1-p$ for T, you should find
$t=\dfrac1p+\dfrac1{p^2q}$.

Comment: that last equation is interesting, so you can say that the probability of getting HTH when there is an even chance for each side 1/8 plus that chance of not getting that is 1/2 when you're at HT so you just sum the expectations of both?

Comment: ?? The idea is that you try to find this formula following the steps in my answer, did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively I feel it makes sense because the probability of getting HTH (or any specific combination) is 1/8.

For one combination of HTH to be included in your series of coin flips, you would have an expected value of 8 sets of three-coin tosses each. ie. 10 total flips. (if the flips were numbered 1-10, the sets of three would be 123;234; ... ;789;8910)

Therefore you will have 8 sets of three-coin flips, and with a 1/8th probability of success your expected number of such combinations is 1.

Comment: The expected waiting time for HTT is 8, and the expected waiting time for HHH is 14. It has to do with how many proper initial sub-strings occur as ending sub-strings, e.g. none for HTT; H for HTH; and both H and HH for HHH.

Answer (score 0):

We can explain this in terms of expectations:
Define:
 
$E_{HTH} =$ number of flips to obtain $HTH$ 
$E_{H,TH} =$ number of flips to obtain $HTH$ given that we flipped $H$
$E_{HT,H} =$ number of flips to obtain $HTH$ given that we flipped $HT$
etc. 
Let $p,q$ be the success and failure probabilities respectively.

Then:

$E_{HTH} = 2 + p ^{2}E_{H,TH}+pqE_{HT,H}+pqE_{H,TH}+q^2E_{HTH}$
$E_{H,TH}=1+pE_{H,TH}+qE_{HT,H}\implies E_{H,TH}=(1+qE_{HT,H})/q$
$E_{HT,H} = 1 + p * 0 + qE_{HTH}=1 + qE_{HTH}$
Substituting we get, 
$E_{HTH}= \frac{2+(p^2+pq)(\frac{1}{q}+1)+pq}{1-(qp^{2}+2pq^{2}+q^{2})} $
Plugging in $p=q=\frac{1}{2}$, yields $10$.