# Expected time to see pattern in stream

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a infinite incoming stream, whose elements are drawn uniformly at random from $\{1, 2, ..., N\}$. We also have a length-$k$ pattern $S$, whose elements are drawn in the same way.

Let $X$ be the number of elements we need to inspect in the stream before we see $S$. For example, with stream $[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]$ and pattern $[3, 4]$, $X$ equals $3$. I want to calculate $E[X]$.

The way I calculate this is to treat each element in the stream as the beginning of a length-$k$ sequence. $E[X]$ is then simply $N^k$.

Is this correct? One point I'm particularly worried about is that I treat those overlapping sequences in the stream as if they are independent.

Comment: Not quite. There are many similar questions asking the expected number of coin flips to obtaining a particular sequences. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816140/why-is-the-expected-number-coin-tosses-to-get-hth-is-10 demonstrating the markov chain method.

Comment: @BGM Thank you, I've read the linked post. But I'm wondering if the fact that my pattern is random somehow justifies my method? I.e., does the randomness of the pattern allows us to treat the overlapping sequences as if they are independent?