# Expected number of times $HHT$ appears in $n$ tosses

Tags: probability, expectation

I want to know if the following reasoning is correct for this problem:

We assign the random variable $X_i$ which takes value $1$ if $HHT$ pattern starts at index $i$ in the sequence of outcomes, and $0$ otherwise.

So, $E(X_i) = \frac 1{8}$

Let $X$ be total expected number.

Then by linearity of expectation, we will get $E(X) =  \frac {n-2}8$

Comment: 'n' is the number of tosses an unbiased coin is tossed

Comment: Yes, the correct reasoning!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. The $X_i$ are not independent, but for expectation that doesn't matter.

(edited to discuss a question in the comments) If you want the expected number of tosses until you get a HHT, you can do that as follows. Let this number be $x$; it's easy to see that $x<\infty$.

If the first toss is T, you have used up a toss and have to start again. So the conditional expected number given the first toss is T is $1+x$. Similarly, conditional on starting HT the expected number is $2+x$. The only remaining possibility is a start of HH - now the next tail will complete a HHT, and the expected number of tosses is $4$ ($2$ you've already done, plus $2$ on average to get a tail). So
$$x=\frac12(1+x)+\frac14(2+x)+\frac14(4),$$
and solving this gives $x=8$.

Comment: A different but related question: if I want to calculate expected number of tosses to get HHT, as done here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816140/why-is-the-expected-number-coin-tosses-to-get-hth-is-10) do I just put $(n-2)/8 = 1$ to get $n=10$ or is it a coincidence?

Comment: @johndoe It's a coincidence (as far as I can see) that it works for HTH, which is what the linked question is looking at. It doesn't work for HHT, where the expected number of tosses is actually $8$.

Comment: I got 11 as the answer by the relation $x = 1/2(x+1)[T] + 1/2[H](1/2 . 1/2 . 3[HT after H] + 1/2(x+2)[T after H] + 1/2 . 1/2 . x[HH after H])$

Comment: @johndoe the last term isn't right - if you start with HHH you don't expect $x$ tosses. I've done a simulation to check, and $x=8$ is correct.