# Expected tosses until HTH

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Trying to understand the reasoning in the provided answer by Vikas Jain in this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816140/why-is-the-expected-number-coin-tosses-to-get-hth-is-10)

What I’m confused about is when they say that if the first two tosses are heads, then the expected number of tosses is still x. However I would have thought since the sequence has gone HH, the first toss is ‘wasted’ but the second head can be used as the first in the HTH sequence. Since we are starting ‘one toss in’ I would have thought the expected number of tosses would be x+1, not x?

I’m clearly missing something as 10 is the correct answer.

Please answer without Markov chains. Just looking for error in my reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer of Vikas Jain confusing, and since you don't want a Markov chain, I am giving an alternative answer which you may like.

Let $x,y,z$ be the number of tosses needed to get $H, HT, HTH$ respectively

- By the geometric distribution, $x=2$
- *Since you can only advance from here*, again use the geometric distribution to get $y=2+2=4$
- Finally, $z = 4 +0.5 + 0.5(z+1) \Longrightarrow z =10$

Answer (score 0):

You can justify it by saying that if $x$ is the expected number needed at the start and if $y$ is the expected additional number needed after a single $H$, then at the start you toss once with $x= \frac12 (1+x)+\frac12(1+y)$, giving $y=x-2$.

So if you start with $HH$ then the expected additional number needed is still $y$, since the second H is potentially useful, but you used two tosses to get there, making the value of interest $y+2=x$.

Comment: Thank you. I think I follow. I think the error in my understanding was that x is the expected number before you do any tossing, but if you toss HH… then you are ‘in the experiment’ … effectively on your ‘first’ toss of heads… (potentially on the way to the sequence of interest HTH)… so it’s not right to say the expected number is x + 1 because x is the expected number before any toss has occurred… (or rather the expected number from the initial state/initial tail or TT)?

Comment: something like that